# Funktioniert zustimmendes "allerdings" für jede Sorte Statement gleich gut?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Das Wort "allerdings" wird oft benutzt, um einer Aussage zuzustimmen.

> "Das ist so und so."
>   "Allerdings."

Ich habe allerdings (haha) das Gefühl, dass es vor allem bei negativen, skeptischen oder überraschten Statements verwendet wird.

> "Das ist [schlecht/komisch/eine Überraschung …]."

Bei rein positiven Aussagen fühlt es sich für mich ein wenig fehl am Platz an.

> "Das Konzert war echt super." "Allerdings."

- Bilde ich mir das ein, oder ist da tatsächlich eine Tendenz? (keine feste Regel natürlich)
- Was sagt man, um durch und durch positiven Aussagen zuzustimmen?

Comment: "Bilde ich mir das ein...?" -> Ja – "Was sagt man, um durch und durch positiven Aussagen zuzustimmen?" -> Allerdings ;)

Comment: je länger ich über *allerdings* nachdenke, desto komischer ist das Wort. Aber ich glaube du hast recht. Ich denke *genau* ist das gegenteilige Wort (sagt man also eher bei positiven Aussagen).

Comment: Wie nennt man das Phänomen, wenn man ein Wort über und über wiederholt und es von mal zu mal fremder und falscher klingt? – *Genau* und *Allerdings* sind keine gegenteilige Wörter. Sie sind hier schlicht synonym. Allerdings muss ich hier einschränkend erwähnen, wenn ich deine letzte Aussage hätte bestätigen wollen, hätte ich *Genau* gewählt, nicht *Allerdings*. Liegt imho an "Ich denke, dass ..." In deinem Bsp-Satz oben wäre das genau so. Auf "Die waren so begeistert, ich glaube, das Konzert war echt super." würde ich nicht mit *Allerdings* antworten, jedoch auch nicht mit *Genau*. Anyway.

Comment: Ich sehe allerdings auch einen kleinen Unterschied zw. *allerdings* und *genau*. Für mich hat *allerdings* eine stärkere Unterstreichung. Es wird auch wesentlich seltener verwendet als *genau*. *Genau* verwendet man außerdem noch in Sätzen wie "Genau das glaube ich auch" oder "Ich sehe das genau so". Nicht selten kann ein solcher Satz einfach mit *genau* abgekürzt werden, vermutlich macht man es auch so (hab dazu natürlich keinen Beleg). Vllt liegt es daran, dass du in dem Konzert-Bsp eher zu *genau* tendieren würdest.

Comment: @Em1... für dich wäre es also völlig normal auf "Das war das beste Essen seit langem" mit "Allerdings." antworten? Und das würde dann für dich uneingeschränkt begeistert klingen?

Comment: @Emanuel Ich würde diese Aussage so verstehen, dass es vor allem eine Kritik an den anderen Essen ist oder aber eben gar nicht gut war, sondern nur besser.

Comment: @Phira... also würdest du mir zustimmen, dass da irgendwie was negatives oder skeptisches drin ist?

Answer (score 3):

In der Tat verwenden wir die Antwort *Allerdings* häufiger im negativen als im positiven Sinne. Das liegt aber nicht daran, dass es eine Regel gäbe, die besagt, dass *allerdings* nicht im positiven verwendet werden dürfe.

Die Ungebräuchlichkeit entsteht vielmehr dadurch, dass wir dazu neigen, negative Kommentare kürzer und bündiger zu formulieren, um unsere geknickte Haltung oder gar Enttäuschung deutlich zu machen.

Umgekehrt wirkt es merkwürdig, wenn sich einige Menschen zum Beispiel angeregt über einen Film unterhalten und von einem Gesprächsteilnehmer lediglich ein *Allerdings* beigesteuert wird.
Unterbewusst vermuten wir aufgrund dieser abgehackten Antwort, dass diese ironisch war oder, und das deutlich wahrscheinlicher, dass unseren Gegenüber das Gesprächsthema nicht (mehr) interessiert.

*Vergleiche kurze bündige Antworten, um ein Telefongespräch zum Ende zu bringen.*

So komme ich zum Schluss, dass du die negative Tendenz (entgegen den anderen Kommentaren) richtig vermutest.

Comment: Demzufolge müsste ich jetzt das ganze mit "Allerdings" kommentieren... Was ich allerdings als absolut unangebracht empfinde.

Comment: Wirklich liebenswert. Danke.
Um mich selbst zu zitieren: "Die Ungebräuchlichkeit entsteht..." In der tat wäre die Antwort "allerdings" in deinem Fall ungebräuchlich und unpassend. Da sind wir einer Meinung.

Comment: Ich würde allerdings auch nicht als Ein-Wort-Antwort benutzen.
Einfach weil es mir nicht eindeutig genug wäre.
Aber das ist wie deine nur meine Meinung.

Answer (score 3):

Ich möchte in meiner Antwort erstmal weiter an den Aussagen in meinen Kommentaren festhalten (es wird sehr wohl für positive Rückmeldungen verwendet), dann allerdings auch einräumen, dass ich verstehen kann, woher das Gefühl kommt, dass es eher für negative Aussagen verwendet würde (was wirklich nicht so ist).

Erst einmal ist *allerdings*, als Interjektion verwendet, synonym zu Ausdrücken wie *Genau*, *Stimmt* oder *Aber Hallo*.

> Das Essen war aber gut.
>   Allerdings.

In dieser Verwendung wird Bestätigung bzw. Zustimmung ausgedrückt.

Nun kann man aber auch negative Aussagen auf die gleiche Weise bestätigen:

> Das Essen war nicht gut.
>   Allerdings.

Allerdings wird *allerdings* auch verwendet, um etwas einzuräumen oder einzuschränken. Hier kann es (auf den ersten Blick) nicht positiv verwendet werden.

> Das Essen war gut, allerdings zu wenig. (einschränkend)
>   Das Essen war nicht gut, allerdings habe ich es auch nicht anders erwartet. (einräumend)
>   *Das Essen war gut, allerdings auch reichlich. (falsche Verwendung)

Der Vergleich hinkt vielleicht, dennoch möchte ich hier kurz auf das Wort *billig* zu sprechen kommen.

Wenn ich sage

> Das T-Shirt ist aber billig.

beziehe ich mich eindeutig nur auf den Preis. Dennoch suggeriert diese Aussage gerade in heutiger Zeit auch eine Kritik an der Qualität. Das habe ich aber weder gesagt noch gemeint.

Im Bezug auf *allerdings* kann das bedeuten, dass auch hier eine Aussage suggeriert werden kann, welche nie gesagt wurde. Wenn also *allerdings* eine oft einräumende oder einschränkende Funktion hat, warum sollte sie dann bei der Interjektion nicht auch herausgehört werden?!

Allerdings muss man hier auch erwähnen, dass eine Aussage mit Hilfe von *allerdings* durch und durch positiv sein kann. Zwei Beispiele:

> […] Das Essen hat mir allerdings geschmeckt.
>   […] Das ist allerdings wahr.

Beide Aussagen sind zweifellos positiv behaftet, obwohl in beiden Fällen etwas eingeräumt wird.
Ich möchte hier insbesondere auf den zweiten Beispielsatz eingehen. Die Aussage "Das ist wahr" ist bereits positiv behaftet und wird durch *allerdings* verstärkt. Hier steckt aber auch drin, dass ich zuvor an der Korrektheit gezweifelt habe (was ich hier einräume; vielleicht aufgrund eines stichhaltigen Arguments) und infolgedessen nun vollkommen zustimme.
Ein zweiter Anwendungsfall könnte aber auch sein, eine Tatsache schlicht zu bestätigen (welches dann zu nur *Allerdings* gekürzt werden kann):

> Das Wetter ist heute schön.
>   Allerdings./Das ist allerdings wahr.

Hier können durchaus Überraschung und Verwunderung suggeriert werden (ich habe nicht damit gerechnet, dass heute so schönes Wetter ist). Allerdings drückt die Interjektion "Stimmt" genauso viel (oder wenig) Überraschung aus wie *allerdings*. Insofern ist das *allerdings* nicht anders als alle anderen Ausdrücke auch. Außerdem muss hinter der Aussage in keinster Weise Verwunderung stecken. In den meisten Fällen ist es schlichtweg Bestätigung.

Fazit:
*Allerdings* kann einen negativen Beigeschmack haben. Es kann Überraschung ausdrücken, es kann zuvor Gesagtes einschränken oder Fehler einräumen. Dies ist aber nicht immer der Fall, und es wäre falsch immer etwas Negatives zu suchen. *Allerdings* kann ohne Wenn und Aber schlichtweg Bestätigung und Übereinstimmung vermitteln, ohne dabei irgendeine Art von Zweifel, Verwunderung oder sonstigem negativem Beigeschmack zu vermitteln.

Comment: "Ich mag schwimmen"... kann auch Konditional sein. Die Frage war nicht, was es kann sondern für was es mehrheitlich verwendet wird. Das Fazit geht also ein bisschen an der Frage vorbei. Natürlich trotzdem +1